# Does a procedure call in the same object module require relocation in the link stage

Tags: c, linux, compilation, linker, gnu

I assumed a procedure call in the same object module wouldn't require relocation in the link stage. e.g. following code

```
void callee()
{
    printf("Should I be relocated\n");
}
void caller()
{
    callee();
}
```

After compile/assemble, I got following

```
Relocation section '.rel.text' at offset 0x438 contains 3 entries:
Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
00000009  00000501 R_386_32          00000000   .rodata
0000000e  00000a02 R_386_PC32        00000000   puts
0000001b  00000902 R_386_PC32        00000000   callee
```

And the result of disassembly:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <callee>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
   6:   c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
   d:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   e <callee+0xe>
  12:   c9                      leave  
  13:   c3                      ret    

00000014 <caller>:
  14:   55                      push   %ebp
  15:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  17:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
  1a:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   1b <caller+0x7>
  1f:   c9                      leave  
  20:   c3                      ret
```

Why does the procedure call in a same object module (1a:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   1b ) need relocation? Does it depend on my toolchain? Does the PC-relative address (the address offset between the caller and callee) ever have chance to change when calling the procedure within a same object module? If not, why not just fix the code at 0x1a to "e8 e1 ff ff ff"

Comment: Your function is globally visible and could be called from any other compilation unit. Therefore the compiler creates code that allows the function to be called from anywhere outside your module. The compiler does not know that you will only call it from within `caller`. You might try to make your function `static` and check the code again.

Comment: If callee is called from other object module, the compiler just create a relocation entry for the callee in that module. In my original question, the call to callee is from the same module and if the PC-relative address from the caller to the callee doesn't change, there is no need for the relocation at all.  You are right, if the callee is defined as static in my original code, the relocation entry for callee is eliminated. But the question still remains as for the original case.

Comment: The compiler might use one method for calling static functions and one for calling public functions. Why would it invent a third way, if these two are sufficient?

Comment: Relocation tables are stored inside each module, for *that* actual module. Load-time relocation of shared libs wouldn't be possible otherwise.

Comment: Depending on the architecture function calls made within a module and made across modules may also require different ways to return to caller. As your function is not restricted to your module, it must be able to return as if it was called across functions. And therefore it also must be called as it would be called from another module. Your caller function must use the address from relocation table instead of PC relative operations.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the different ways to return to caller and how it requires the callee to be relocated in my specific example?

Answer (score 2):

Relocation tables have to be stored inside each module, for *that* actual module, to allow load-time relocation of shared libs.

Since the dynamic linker in (most) Unix distributions can override functions in shared libraries, this means that the function can be relocated, even if the call happens inside a single module. Tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) benefit from such features for instrumentation and leak detection.

So, as noted in comments, if you mark the function `static`, then the compiler can skip this part altogether and hardcode the jump.

Comment: Yes, the function can be relocated. In my example, the callee can be relocated. But the relocation happens on the section not a single function, right? That will keep the offset between callee and caller constant. I can't think out the necessity to relocate the call to callee in my specific example, if the offset is kept constant.